# can LLVM IR (Intermediate Representation) be used to create cross-platform (iphone and Android) ARM executables?

Tags: iphone, android, embedded, arm, llvm

I'm looking into possible means of efficiently creating an Android and iPhone targeted application from the same code base, be it in C/C++/C#/Objective-C or Java (using VMKit).

LLVM looks promising, however I'm slightly confused regarding compatibility issues surrounding the differing ARM CPU implementations, mainly from the aspect of how graphics and sound code are 'resolved' by underlying chipsets (i.e. do I have to code to specific ARM chipsets, or will a higher-level API, like OpenGL, suffice?).

I do know a little about various Cross Dev products (i.e. Airplay SDK, MoSync (GPL-GCC), Unity3d, XMLVM etc.), but what I'd really like to do is either write in Java or use a C/C++ engine, emit LLVM IR and create compatible ARM executables, if possible.

Apologies if any of the above is vague.

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not the problem.  To develop for both you need to create an abstraction layer that allows you to write a single application on that layer.  Then have two implementations of the abstraction layer, one that makes Android api calls and one that makes iPhone api calls.  There is nothing the compiler can do to help you.

Where LLVM IR might be interesting in its portability is for programs like:

```
int a,b;

a=7;
b=a-4;
```

Compile to IR then take the same IR and generate assembler for all the different processor types and examine the differences.

In the case of real applications that for example need to write a pixel on a display, the registers, sizes of the display and a whole host of other differences exist, and those differences are not exposed between the IR and the assembler backend but are exposed in the main C program and the api calls defined by the platforms library, so you have to solve the problem in C not IR or assembler.

Answer (score 3):

LLVM is no different from any other compiler in the sense that you need, so I'm afraid the answer is no.

The LLVM IR is in layman's terms a "partly compiled" code, and can be used, say, to compile the rest on the end device. For example, if you have a graphically intensive app, you might ship parts of it in IR, then compile on the device to get the most performance out of the specific hardware.

For what you want, you either need to use one of the products you mentioned, or have native UIs (using Cocoa/VMKit), but possible share the data/logic code in the app

Answer (score 2):

For standard app store legal development for stock OS devices, neither the sound nor the graphics code in an app have anything to do with the underlying chipsets or specific ARM CPU architecture.  The sound and graphics (and all other user IO) are abstracted by each OS through platform dependent APIs and library linkages.  You can either code to each platform's completely different APIs, or use an abstraction layer on top, such as Unity, et. al.

LLVM might allow you to optimize from intermediate code to machine code for certain differences in the ARM architectures (armv6, armv7, fp support, etc.), but only in self-contained code that does no user IO, or otherwise require any higher level interface use to the OS.